# How to make Fabric.js IText font NOT bold?

Tags: fabricjs

[In this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/hsLwjtbx/12/) I have an IText with `fontWeight: 'normal'`, still the font is displayed with bold letters. How to make this text NOT bold?

Javascript:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var text = new fabric.IText('This is the text',{
    left: 20,
    top: 20,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    fontSize: 18,
    stroke: 'black',
    fill: 'black'
});

canvas.add(text);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stroke effect makes it appear bold.

The text itself has the normal standard weight, [here is a comparison without the stroke effect](http://jsfiddle.net/t6wc54Lu/1/).

```
var text = new fabric.IText('This is the text',{
  left: 20,
  top: 20,
  fontFamily: 'Arial',
  fontWeight: 'normal',
  fontSize: 18,
  fill: 'black'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just because of stroke, if you remove the stroke then you will get `fontweight:'Normal'`, please find the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Gauravkakkar25/ruoa19r7/1/